# Correct way to use ばかりか・ばかりでなく

Tags: grammar

I am trying to understand the correct usage of this grammar. I have been taught that ばかりか means 'not only A but also B.'

A Japanese friend mentioned that it is only used to talk about negative things?

I have seen many examples that don't fit this description.
For example:

> 私は英語ばかりか日本語も話せる。
>   彼女は美しいばかりか、心もやさしく、しかも聡明である。

So I tried to practise this grammar by making my own sentences and made many mistakes.

> 1. あなたは美しいばかりか、動物にやさしく、しかも聡明である.

I was told this was wrong...and was changed to and I only changed the subject and one description (from the example sentence above)

> あなたは美しいだけでなく、動物にやさしく、しかも聡明である

I won't go through all of them but here are my (bad) sentences. Maybe you can see what my problem is:

> １．私は水を飲めないばかりか、アイスクリームも食べられない。
>   ２．あなたは美しいばかりか、動物にやさしく、しかも聡明である。
>   ４．私は日本に行ったことあるばかりでなく、中国も行ったことあります。
>   ５．私の国は安いばかりでなく、食べ物もおいしいですよ。
>   ６．私は日本に行きたいばかりか、中国も行きたいですよ。
>   ７．大学で日本語を勉強したばかりか、中国も勉強しました。
>   ８．そればかりか、彼は私を安心させたいばかりに、そんな嘘をおっしゃるのね。
>   ９．リンゴは安いばかりか、ひふにやさしいです。
>   １０．私は漢字を書くことが下手ばかりか、発音も上手じゃない。

Why did they all get changed to だけでなく?

Thank you so so much for your help!

Comment: Because this ばかりか is an exaggerated expression, I think they judged some of your sentences are too much.

Answer (score 11):

I would say ばかりか is more emphatic than simple "not only ～ but also ～", and thus should be used sparingly. Perhaps this construction sounds more like "and what's more/worse...". It's probably true that it tends to be used in negative situations (ie., "what's worse"), but you can use it in positive sentences, too.

I feel ばかりでなく is not as emphatic as ばかりか, but still somewhat more emphatic than だけでなく. だけでなく is safe and neutral.

> 私は英語ばかりか日本語も話せる。

This perfectly makes sense, but sounds like you're fairly proud of being able to speak the two languages — perhaps to the point where you may sound a bit arrogant in business settings. Likewise, Sentences 6 and 7 sound a bit too selfish or confident to me.

> あなたは美しいばかりか、動物にやさしく、しかも聡明である。

Um, I think this sentence is perfect as far as the usage of ばかりか goes. You cannot praise a woman too much.

> 私は水を飲めないばかりか、アイスクリームも食べられない

This is grammatically correct but semantically awkward because the "what's worse" part should come after ばかりか. It's hard to imagine a situation where a sick person cannot drink water but can eat ice cream. "アイスクリームを食べられないばかりか、水も飲めない" is good.

> 私は漢字を書くことが下手ばかりか、発音も上手じゃない。

な or である is required after 下手 (ie 下手なばかりか or 下手であるばかりか). And this doesn't sound natural either, because "being bad at pronunciation" is not really a worse thing than "being bad at writing kanji".

> 私の国は安いばかりでなく、食べ物もおいしいですよ。

Add 物価が or 物【もの】が before 安い; a country cannot be cheap. Otherwise the sentence looks perfect to me.

Regarding Sentence 8, そればかりか at the beginning of the sentence is a valid way of saying "what's more". ばかりに in 安心させたいばかりに is [a different idiom](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=bakarini).

Comment: Thank you so much fo your detailed answer. Just one more thing, would having dakedenaku instead of bakarika make me able to talk about both negative and positive things?

Comment: @ichigohime Yes, だけでなく is neutral and can be used both in negative and positive sentences.

Comment: Would ばかりでなく still imply a negative thing? Or is it simply more formal than だけでなく?

Comment: @eefara ばかりでなく can be used both in positive and negative statements.

Answer (score 1):

According to "A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar", page 8:
ばかりか...(さえ): a compound particle/conjunction which is used to connect two nouns or two sentences, the first of which is normally expected, and the second is normally unexpected.

So in the sentence AばかりかB, A needs to be something expected, while B needs to be something unexpected.

Examples:
日本では子供ばかりか大人さえ漫画を読んでいる。
In Japan not only children but even adults are reading comic books.

Answer (score 0):

On a more general note, the use of か as a negativizer - in this case ばかり (just, only) into "not only" - is quite a forceful negativizer.

There are several expressions that use this and they are all quite strong (I would except the sentence ender じゃないか which is saying that something *is* so by double-negative since this is so common that it lacks much force).

If you think of that か as creating a very condensed rhetorical question "and you think that was all?" I think it becomes clearer why would come across too strong too self-confident. too critical etx. in cases where a less forceful negative would be in order.